# How to optimize valve simulation logic?

Tags: c, opencl, sse, simd, differential-equations

This is an simple logic-programming and optimisation etude, that I've created for myself, and somewhat stumbled upon it.

I have a numerical simulation of simple scheme. Consider some reservoir (or a capacitor) `Cm`, which is constantly pumping up with pressure. Lets call its current state `Vm`:

[image]

At its output it has a valve, or a gate, `G`, that could be open or closed, according to following logic:

- Gate opens, when pressure(or voltage) `Vm` exceeds some threshold, call it `Vopen`: `Vm > Vopen`
- Gate remains open, while current outrush `Ia` is greater than some `Ihold`: `Ia > IHold`
- Gate conducts power only out of reservoir (like a diode)

I am doing numerical ODE solving of this, i.e. determining `Vm` and `Ia` at each (equal, small) timestep dt. Have three variants of this:

---

### Variable types:

```
float Vm=0.0, Ia=0.0, Vopen, Ihold, Ra, dt;
int G=0;
```

---

### Loop body v1 (serial):

```
Vm = Vm + (-Ia*G)*dt;
G |= (Vm > Vopen);
Ia = Ia + (Vm*Ra*G)*dt;
G &= (Ia > Ihold);
```

---

### Loop body v2 (serial, with temp var, ternary conditionals):

```
int Gv; // temporary var
Vm = Vm + (-Ia*G)*dt;
Gv = (Vm > Vopen) ? 1 : G; 
Ia = Ia + (Vm*Ra*Gv)*dt;
G = (Ia > Ihold) ? Gv : 0;
```

---

### Loop body v3 (parallel, with cache):

```
// cache new state first
float Vm1 = Vm + (-Ia*G)*dt;
float Ia1 = Ia + (Vm*Ra*G)*dt;
// update memory
G = ( Vm1 > Vopen ) || (( Ia1 > Ihold ) && G);
Vm = Vm1;
Ia = Ia1; // not nesesary to cache, done for readibility
```

the G was taken from building up the following truth table, plus imagination:
[image]

---

### Q:

- Which is correct? Are they?
- How third variant(parallel logic) differs from first two(serial logic)?
- Are there more effective ways of doing this logic?

PS. I am trying to optimize it for SSE, and then (separately) for OpenCL (if that gives optimisation hints)

PPS. For those who is curious, here is [my working simulator](https://jsfiddle.net/zo2xuhds/embedded/result), involving this gate (html/js)

Comment: @PeterCordes Looking up for some SSE gurus ;-) How would you solve this etude?

Comment: These calculations are very simple, there is not much room for optimisation here. BTW why do you use `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky There are at least 3 variants, I feel like something is incorrect even in such simple thing, as I wrote it (q1). Also, whats difference between parallel and serial? (q2) `float` is just a habit, shorter to type :) Precision here is of no matter, they are just a clues for types (eg "here are some floating point variables")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By the overall description they are the same and should all fulfil your needs.
2. Your serial code will produce half-steps. That means if you break it down to the discrete description V(t) can be described as being 1/2 dt in front of I(t). The fist one will keep G changing in every half-step and the second one will synchronise it to I. But since you are not evaluating G in between in doesn't really matter. There is also no real problem with V and I being a half step apart but you should keep it in mind but maybe you should use for plotting/evaluation the vector {V(t),(I(t-1)+I(t))/2,G(t)}.

   The parallel code will keep them all in the same time step.
3. For your pure linear problem the direct integration is a good solution. Higher order ode solver won't buy you anything. State-space representation for pure linear systems only write the same direct integration in a different way.

For SIMD optimisation there isn't munch to do. You need to evaluate step-wise since you are updating I by V and V by I. That means you can't run the steps in parallel which makes many interesting optimisation not possible.

Comment: They would produce different results ;)

Comment: @xakepp35 I even described you why. But that is a discrete simulation so you will always have errors in it and you have to know the limitations of your simulation.

Comment: Parallel code seems allows for more optimisations than serial, as it updates I by Iprev, and V by Vprev, at the cost of extra register. But are all three conditions right and equal?

Comment: @xakepp35 Yes a little bit more maybe possible. But not munch. You may run one multiplication more in parallel. But I wouldn't bet on a better performance. You may get more by reordering the multiplications to have the common terms in front. The conditions are equal as long as you keep the different stepping in mind. So the results will not be equal but equivalent.

Comment: If you're "throwing a rock", aiming at algorightm precision - you'd need to integrate coordinate `x`, and velocity `v` in steps, according to newton law. Which of two schemes would give you least error at the end - serial or parallel?

Comment: @xakepp35 Depends on what you simulate. If you are doing it in free space. x(t) is independent of v(t) and the other way around. You can describe both only depending on t. If you simulate it with air resistance you have F(t) ~ v^2(t) and should use a higher order ode solver.

Comment: (you mean that is what I call "parallel"?)

Comment: @xakepp35 No, first one is the same in "parallel" and "serial" and second depends on your solver.

Comment: I am not good at therminology, eg solver/order.. i forget that for years, trying to relearn.. look, in first two idea is sequential "voltage builds up, then checking for gate to release it, then updating current, then checking if gate is holding open next time we build up voltage". and third idea is that in real world all processes are simultaneous, so we must tie to steps as precisely as possible". i dont remember what is higher order ode, and even cant write runge-kutta solver by memory. so sorry, dont understant quite (probably i werent asking this..)

Comment: @xakepp35 Your real world not only run in parallel but also in a continuous and not discrete time. Therefore, both version are valid if you understand how your discrete time is mapped to the continuous time in real life and vice versa. Both version have different mapping and will therefore result in slightly different results but not in a substantial way if you keep dt small enough.

Comment: How to turn this to verlet integration scheme?